# Regarding package in java

Tags: java

I have following directory structure.

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\Beer-v1\WEB-INF\classes\com\example\model\BeerExpert.java
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\Beer-v1\WEB-INF\classes\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java
```

The source code for BeerSelect is

```
package com.example.web;
import com.example.model.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;


public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException,ServletException
{
String c=req.getParameter("color");
BeerExpert be=new BeerExpert();
List result=be.getBrands(c);
res.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
out.println("Beer Selection Advice<br>");
Iterator it=result.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
out.println("<br>try: "+it.next());
}
}
}
```

and source code for BeerExpert is

```
package com.example.model;
import java.util.*;

public class BeerExpert
{
public List getBrands(String color)
{
List brands=new ArrayList();
if(color.equals("amber"))
{
brands.add("Jack Amber");
brands.add("Red Moose");
}
else
{
brands.add("Jail Pale Ale");
brands.add("Gout Stout");
}
return(brands);
}
}
```

Beer Expert is compiling fine but whenevr i am running BeerSelect its giving me an error

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\Beer-v1\WEB-INF\classes\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java:2: package com.example.model does not exist
import com.example.model.*;
^
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\Beer-v1\WEB-INF\classes\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol : class BeerExpert
location: class com.example.web.BeerSelect
BeerExpert be=new BeerExpert();
^
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\Beer-v1\WEB-INF\classes\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol : class BeerExpert
location: class com.example.web.BeerSelect
BeerExpert be=new BeerExpert();
```

^
3 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1

Comment: What command are you using to compile?  Are you in an IDE?  Are you using a build tool?

Comment: @OverZealous - Hi ia m using Textpad...not eclipse.I am using following command to compile it...
c:\program files\apache\tomact 6\webapps\Beer-v1\WEB-INF>javac classes\com\example\model\BeerExpert.java

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the CLASSPATH to include BeerExpert? Include the **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\Beer-v1\WEB-INF\classes** directory into the CLASSPATH

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the wrong build location.  You need to be in `WEB-INF\classes` for the relative paths.  IE, run this first:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\Beer-v1\WEB-INF\classes"
```

You might also have to add `-classpath .;%CLASSPATH%` to the command line argument.

Full command as requested:

```
C:\> cd "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\Beer-v1\WEB-INF\classes"
C:\program files\apache\tomact 6\webapps\Beer-v1\WEB-INF\classes> javac -classpath .;%CLASSPATH% com\example\model\BeerExpert.java
```

Comment: @OverZealous-can you helpme out with ful command so that i can run it?